# Why is my method creating an extra list within a list? Leetcode 3Sum question

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

This is a solution for leetcode 3sum problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/

I think I have a solution, might be slow but nonetheless a solution. But I cant seem to figure out why I keep getting an extra list. Basically for the `input:nums = [-1,0,1,2,-1,-4]`
I should get back from my code the output: `[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]`.
But instead I am getting: `[[-1, 2, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 1, 0]]`.

I tried using this to remove the duplicate list, but I think there is some logical error being made to cause this extra list. Here is that code to remove duplicate lists within list, wasn't giving any useful output, just memory location.

**code:**

```
dup_set = set(map(tuple,a))
non_dup_set = map(list,dup_set)
```

Was also thinking I might need a hashmap so that the method knows not to re-use indexes but my understanding of hashmaps is not that good, I just think key-values, but nothing beyond that.

**Here is the full code:**

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        nums.sort()
        l = 0
        r = len(nums) - 1
        final_list = []
        
        while l < r:
            if nums[l] + nums[r] <= 0:
                print(nums[l+1:r])
                if (nums[l] + nums[r]) in nums[l+1:r]:
                    final_list.append([nums[l],nums[r],(nums[l]+nums[r])])
                l+=1
            elif nums[l] + nums[r] >= 0:
                print(nums[l+1:r])
                if -(nums[l] + nums[r]) in nums[l+1:r]:
                    final_list.append([nums[l],nums[r],(nums[l]+nums[r])])
                r-=1

        print(final_list)
            
            
Solution().threeSum([-1,0,1,2,-1,-4])
```

Output: `[[-1, 2, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 1, 0]]`

Desired: `[[-1, 2, 1], [-1, 1, 0]]`

Please help
Thank you

Comment: Your logic is flawed.  Regardless of the sign of `nums[l] + nums[r]`, you need the negative of that value to be in the list, not the positive.  You don't need the first `if` clause there.  That won't eliminate duplicates, however.

Comment: Note, for example, that [-1,2,1] is not correct: the sum is 2, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go like this:

```
non_dup_set = list(set(map(tuple, a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this answer.  It gets the right tuples, although not in the same order.  Not sure why that should matter.

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        final_list = []
        for l, v1 in enumerate(nums):
            for r, v2 in enumerate(nums[l+1:]):
                if -(v1+v2) in nums[l+r+1:]:
                    check = sorted((v1,v2,-(v1+v2)))
                    if check not in final_list:
                        final_list.append(check)
        print(final_list)

Solution().threeSum([-1,0,1,2,-1,-4])
```

An even better answer uses `itertools.combinations` to simplify things:

```
import itertools
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        final_list = []
        for subset in itertools.combinations(nums,3):
            if sum(subset) == 0:
                check = sorted(subset)
                if check not in final_list:
                    final_list.append(check)
        print(final_list)

Solution().threeSum([-1,0,1,2,-1,-4])
```

And the obligatory one-liner:

```
import itertools
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums):
        final_list = list(set(tuple(sorted(subset)) for subset in itertools.combinations(nums,3) if sum(subset) == 0))
        print(final_list)

Solution().threeSum([-1,0,1,2,-1,-4])
```

Comment: Thanks but in the case of [[0,0,0]] it failed.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.  None of those will produce [0,0,0] from your input, and if you feed [0,0,0] they will all produce [[0,0,0]] as output, which is exactly right.  There is nothing wrong with my code.